# JavaScript how to listen the text content value changes in a option tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The text content value inside the tag will change dynamically, each time if I click the submit button, new text content will be added into the option tag.

Now I want to add a listener for the tag ,so that each new text content added to the tag ,the height of the tag will be increased.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button>Submit</button>
<select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-1" id="purchaserSelect">
  <option onchange="addLength();">CCCCInvesDD, LC, and Life Company, ASAA Funding, AAAA Acquisition, LLC, BCATAAAA, BCAT 2020-3TT, AAAA, LLC,DDDD Investment Holdings LLC,CCCC Realty Holdings LLC</option>
</select>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
function addLength(){
  const select = document.querySelector('#purchaserSelect');
  select.style.height = select.offsetHeight + "px";
}
```